# How can I remove wrapper (parent element) without removing the child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I would like to remove the parent without removing the child - is this possible?

HTML structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src"">
</div>
<div class="button">Remove wrapper</div>
```

After clicking on the button I would like to have:

```
<img src"">
<div class="button">Remove wrapper</div>
```

Comment: You may lose the event listeners attached to the children, but yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could use this API: http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/7GrbM/

`.unwrap`

Code will look something on these lines:

**Sample Code**

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('.wrapper img').unwrap();
});
```

Comment: should it be  $('.wrapper img').unwrap() ?

Comment: +1 and if there are more contents then `$('.wrapper').children().unwrap();`

Comment: Merci Yo! `:)` your +1 is gracefully accepted, cheers for more stuff for OP.

Comment: +1 and if (sometimes) there's only text content (i.e. no child elements), then `$('.wrapper').contents().unwrap();`

Answer (score 62):

Pure JS (*ES2015*) solution, in my opinion easier to read than jQuery-solutions.

```js
node.replaceWith(...node.childNodes)
```

Node has to be an [ElementNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)

```js
const wrapperNode = document.querySelector('h1')
wrapperNode.replaceWith(...wrapperNode.childNodes)
```

```html
<h1>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2</b>
  <em>3</em>
</h1>
```

Comment: With typescript:
```const unwrap = (node: Element) => {
    node.replaceWith(...Array.from(node.children));
};```

Comment: Keeps child event listeners and simple solution.

Answer (score 34):

Pure JS solution that doesn't use innerHTML:

```
function unwrap(wrapper) {
    // place childNodes in document fragment
    var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    while (wrapper.firstChild) {
        var child = wrapper.removeChild(wrapper.firstChild);
        docFrag.appendChild(child);
    }

    // replace wrapper with document fragment
    wrapper.parentNode.replaceChild(docFrag, wrapper);
}
```

#### [Try it](http://jsbin.com/hipahu/edit?html,js,output):

```
unwrap(document.querySelector('.wrapper'));
```

Comment: why is avoiding innerHTML preferable?

Comment: @ajbeaven Keeping the existing DOM objects (rather than recreating them using innerHTML) means any event listeners attached to them are maintained.

Comment: Nice solution, but there is no need to remove the children from the wrapper since `docFrag.appendChild(wrapper.firstChild);` will automatically move a node from its current position to its new position. [Read more about appendChild on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Answer (score 21):

Surprised that nobody's posting the simplest answer:

```
// Find your wrapper HTMLElement
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

// Replace the whole wrapper with its own contents
wrapper.outerHTML = wrapper.innerHTML;
```

Comment: interesting even if you loose listener

Answer (score 6):

Pure javascript solution, i'm sure someone can simplify it more but this is an alternative for pure javascript guys.

HTML

```
<div class="button" onclick="unwrap(this)">Remove wrapper</div>
```

Javascript (pure)

```
function unwrap(i) {
    var wrapper = i.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0];
    // return if wrapper already been unwrapped
    if (typeof wrapper === 'undefined') return false;
    // remmove the wrapper from img
    i.parentNode.innerHTML = wrapper.innerHTML + i.outerHTML;
    return true;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/H3k9S/1/)

Comment: check you working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7GrbM/2/) some problem after unwrapping. Fix it .

Comment: Using `innerHTML` is evil, it will delete all your events inside the HTML.

Comment: @julmot clearly... (: if you want a solution that does that, scroll up or down and you'll find it. I'm not here to create duplicate answers especially when the question didn't ask to keep the event handlers. (;

Answer (score 1):

if you're using jQuery:

```
$(".wrapper").replaceWith($(".wrapper").html());
```

Answer (score -2):

If the wrapper element contains text, the text remains with child nodes.