# Select odd even child excluding the hidden child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Line 3 is a hidden `<div>` . I don't want that one to be taken from the `odd/even css` rule.

[image]

What is the best approach to get this to work?

```css
.hidden {display:none;}
.box:not(.hidden):nth-child(odd)  { background: orange; }
.box:not(.hidden):nth-child(even) { background: green;  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box hidden">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k0wzoweh/

Note: There can be multiple `hidden` elements.

Comment: `:nth-of-type` odd and even, Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/6dnaep2w/

Comment: @MaryMelody doesn't work, even in your fiddle. Pseudo-selectors don't stack

Comment: Can you have a `.visible` class and just do it like that?

Comment: Can you just add an additional hidden div either before or after the other?  I am not clear on what problem you are trying to solve and what constraints you are under. If you want the visible ones to alternate and the invisible one will not become visible, you should state so.

Comment: wow I thought this is it @MaryMelody but it is not :( if I try your fiddle and add another `<div class="box hidden"></div>` right after the hidden one it changes the colors which shouldn't happen ...

Comment: @Reid I've boxes which can on click change the visiblity to `display:none;` and then the odd/even doesn't work for me ..

Comment: :nth-of-type only works on **type**, thus it's looking for `div` elements. If the hidden element would be a `p` instead of a `div`, @MaryMelody's solution would work.

Comment: Updated my answer - I'm even more sure you can't do it now, because not even `.box[class='box']:nth-of-type(even)` works (stacking pseudo and attribute selectors)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pseudo-selectors don't stack, so your `:not` doesn't affect the `:nth-child` (nor would it affect `:nth-of-type` etc.

If you can resort to jQuery, you can use the `:visible` pseudo-selector there, although that's not a part of the CSS spec.

If you're generating the HTML and can change that, you can apply odd/even with logic at run-time, eg in PHP:

```
foreach ($divs AS $i => $div) {
    echo '<div class="box ' . ($i % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd') . '">x</div>';
}
```

Even trying to do something tricky like

```
.box[class='box']:nth-of-type(even)
```

doesn't work, because the psuedo-selector doesn't even stack onto the attribute selector.

I'm not sure there's any way to do this purely with CSS - I can't think of any right now.

Comment: Applying even/odd class at runtime wouldn't work as OP stated that `div` can be clicked and disappear, thus the colors of following elements should change. Javascript is the only way here.

Comment: @Paul in that case, he's already using JS for the click-toggle so using it for maintaining colours shouldn't be an issue, at least :-)

Comment: That's what I thought, but without more code provided it's hard to guess. I could make millions as a clairvoyant at SO. :D

Comment: Correct - simple selectors don't stack. This applies to IDs, classes, attributes and pseudo-classes. Every simple selector operates independently. I'm sure I have this covered somewhere, but oh god, the number of duplicates.

Comment: @BoltClock it's just counter-intuitive, I guess. We're all used to ... well, basically jQuery. Spoiling us with lovely, clean `$('.box:not(.hidden):even')` that just works like you expect, how dare they :P

Comment: Anyway I found one of the answers I was talking about, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5546296 There's got to be a way to consolidate all these first, last, nth, odd/even etc questions into a single canonical question. I think this link fits the bill, although I'll still have to edit it to widen its scope to cover the rest. What do you think?

Comment: @BoltClock I'm struggling to see anything not covered by your answer. It's not all immediately obvious to scan, but the issue isn't simple so I don't think that can really be helped. Definitely the most complete explanation of it I've seen. It **may** be worth incorporating Hashem's answer from below, as this kind of behaviour is common for trying to zebra-stripe rows (I'd say the most common situation it's used in), but then you're adding in potentially unnecessary information

Answer (score 43):

`:nth-child()` pseudo-class looks through the children tree of the parent to match the valid child (`odd`, `even`, etc), therefore when you combine it with `:not(.hidden)` it won't filter the elements properly.

Alternatively, we could fake the effect by CSS gradient as follows:

```css
.hidden {display:none;}

.wrap {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  
  background-color: orange; 
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 50%, green 50%);
  background-size: 100% 2.4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">xx</div>
  <div class="box">xx</div>
  <div class="box hidden">xx</div>
  <div class="box">xx</div>
  <div class="box">xx</div>
  <div class="box">xx</div>
  <div class="box">xx</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice try, but sadly it only works if that particular element is hidden, and no others. If there are 2 hidden rows following each other, it's still has the same error.

Comment: Does not work for:
`<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">xx</div>
  <div class="box hidden">xx</div>
  <div class="box">xx</div>
  <div class="box">xx</div>
  <div class="box hidden">xx</div>
  <div class="box">xx</div>
  <div class="box hidden">xx</div>
  <div class="box hidden">xx</div>
  <div class="box">xx</div>
</div>`

Answer (score 10):

Here's a CSS-only solution:

```css
.box {
  background: orange;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background: green;
}

.box.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.box.hidden ~ .box:nth-child(odd) {
  background: green;
}

.box.hidden ~ .box:nth-child(even) {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">xx</div>
  <div class="box">xx</div>
  <div class="box hidden">xx</div>
  <div class="box">xx</div>
  <div class="box">xx</div>
  <div class="box">xx</div>
  <div class="box">xx</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working if two hidden elements are one right after the other: https://jsfiddle.net/nuxcskx5/ or if there are multiple `hidden` elements: https://jsfiddle.net/nuxcskx5/1/

Comment: Original question doesn't ask for multiple hidden elements.

Comment: That's right, I've tried to keep the question simple. it's only noted in the comments. will update the question. sorry for that.

Comment: Well, you can use this solution with multiple hidden elements. You just have to repeat the reverting of the background-color on every appearance of a hidden element. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VXRBdR Will lead to ridiculously long selectors, but it works.

Answer (score 9):

Since my rows are being hidden with js, I found that the easiest approach for me was to just add an additional hidden row after each real row that I hide, and remove the hidden rows when I show the real rows again.

Comment: I was going to answer this, but found your answer. Nice trick, keeping the css and slightly modifying javascript!

Answer (score 8):

try [Of selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#the_of_selector_syntax)

```
.hidden {display:none;}
.box:nth-child(odd of :not(.hidden))  { background: orange; }
.box:nth-child(even of :not(.hidden)) { background: green; }
```

Comment: this seems to work! thanks (working example: https://jsfiddle.net/75zsu3gx/1/)

Comment: How does this answer not have so much more votes? I just learned of "of" and it kicks a**

Answer (score 4):

Hide the rows you want to hide calling .hide() for each table row, then call

```
$("tr:visible:even").css( "background-color", "" ); // clear attribute for all rows

$("tr:visible:even").css( "background-color", "#ddddff" ); // set attribute for even rows
```

Add your table name to the selector to be more specific. Using `:even` makes it skip the Header row.

Comment: Still useful for me. This is a useful alternative of using `.nth-child` on visible elements only.

Comment: @caramba, maybe not helpful to the OP, but still helpful to scores of people finding the question through search later.

Answer (score 0):

As *[@Fateh Khalsa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39155485/2898929)* pointed out, I had a similar problem and since I was manipulating my table with JavaScript (jQuery to be precise), I was able to do the following:

*(Note: This assumes use of JavaScript/jQuery which the OP did not state whether or not would be available to them.  This answer assumes yes, it would be, and that we may want to toggle visibility of hidden rows at some point.)*

- Inactive records (identified with the CSS class "hideme") are currently visible.
- Visitor clicks link to hide inactive records from the list.
- jQuery adds "hidden" CSS class to "hideme" records.
- jQuery adds additional empty row to the table immediately following the row we just hid, adding CSS classes "hidden" (so it doesn't show) and "skiprowcolor" so we can easily identify these extra rows.

This process is then reversed when the link is clicked again.

- Inactive records (identified with the CSS class "hideme") are currently hidden.
- Visitor clicks link to show inactive records from the list.
- jQuery removes "hidden" CSS class to "hideme" records.
- jQuery removes additional empty row to the table immediately following the row we just showed, identified by CSS class "skiprowcolor".

Here's the JavaScript (jQuery) to do this:

```
// Inactive Row Toggle
$('.toginactive').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
        $(this).removeClass('on');                  // Track that we're no longer hiding rows
        $('.wrap tr.hideme').removeClass('hidden'); // Remove hidden class from inactive rows
        $('.wrap tr.skiprowcolor').remove();        // Remove extra rows added to fix coloring
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('on');                     // Track that we're hiding rows
        $('.wrap tr.hideme').addClass('hidden');    // Add hidden class from inactive rows
        $('.wrap tr.hideme').after('<tr class="hidden skiprowcolor"></tr>');
                                                    // Add extra row after each hidden row to fix coloring
    }
});
```

The HTML link is simple

```
<a href="#" class="toginactive">Hide/Show Hidden Rows</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

scss for @tim answer's above, to keep class name changes to a minimum

```
$selector: "box";
$hidden-selector: "hidden";

.#{$selector} {
  background: orange;

  :nth-child(even) {
    background: green;
  }

  &.#{$hidden-selector} {
    display: none;
  }

  &.#{$hidden-selector} ~ {
    .#{$selector} {
      &:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background: green;
      }

      &:nth-of-type(even) {
        background: orange;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with modern CSS (2023). An expansion of the CSS specification allows you to specify the elements that should be counted by the `:nth-child()` pseudo selector using a second selector list, like this: `tr:nth-child(2n of tr.important)`.

The official syntax looks like this: `:nth-child(<nth> [of <complex-selector-list>]?)`

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#using_of_selector), this has been supported in all major browsers for about 6 months, since May 2023, when Firefox added support. [W3C CSS WG Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)

Example:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
 }
 
tr:nth-child(even of :not(.hidden)){
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Example of "of   &lt;selector&gt;" use</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Year</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Subaru</td><td>Forester</td><td>2021</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ford</td><td>Ranger</td><td>2019</td></tr>
    <tr class="hidden"><td>Nissan</td><td>Rogue</td><td>2015</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Porche</td><td>911 Turbo</td><td>2023</td></tr>
    <tr class="hidden"><td>Toyota</td><td>Corolla</td><td>2009</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Chevy</td><td>Astro</td><td>1999</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way, albeit on the fringe side, is to have an extra `<tbody>` and either move or copy rows there. Or, an extra div wrapper if using OPs example. Copying easiest of course in regards to restoring etc.

This approach can be useful in some cases.

Below is a simple example where rows are moved when filtered. And yes, it is ranking of stripper names, found it fitting as we are talking stripes ... hah

```js
const Filter = {
  table: null,
  last: {
    tt: null,
    value: ''
  },
  name: function (txt) {
    let tb_d = Filter.table.querySelector('.data'),
        tb_f = Filter.table.querySelector('.filtered'),
        tr = tb_d.querySelectorAll('TR'),
        f = 0
    ;
    tb_f.innerHTML = '';
    if (txt.trim() == '') {
      tb_d.classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
      txt = txt.toLowerCase();
      for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) {
        let td = tr[i].querySelectorAll('TD')[1];
        if (td.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(txt)) {
          tb_f.appendChild(tr[i].cloneNode(true));
          f = 1;
        }
      }
      if (f)
        tb_d.classList[f ? 'add' : 'remove']('hide');
    }
  },
  key: function (e) {
    const v = e.target.value;
    if (v == Filter.last.value)
      return;
    Filter.last.value = v;
    clearTimeout(Filter.last.tt);
    Filter.last.tt = setTimeout(function () { Filter.name(v); }, 200);
  }
};

Filter.table = document.getElementById('table');
Filter.table.addEventListener('keyup', Filter.key);
```

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #aaa;
}
tbody tr { background: #e33; }
tbody tr:nth-child(even) { background: #e3e;  }

.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr><th></th><th><input type="text" id="filter" data-keyup="filter" /></th></tr>
    <tr><th>#</th><th>Name</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="filtered">
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="data">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Crystal</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>Tiffany</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>Amber</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>Brandi</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>Lola</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td><td>Angel</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>Ginger</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td><td>Candy</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @caramba: The answer is not about filtering, the filtering is to show the result. Added more contrast to rows to make it more clear.

Answer (score -2):

You can use another type of CSS selector: `tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd)`
to only target `tr` nodes, and then, instead of using class names to hide the rows, simply wrap them with some element (which hides them), so the CSS selector would only match odd table rows:

```js
const searchElem = document.querySelector('input');
const tableElem = document.querySelector('table');
const tableBody = document.querySelector('tbody');

function search() {
  const str = searchElem.value.toLowerCase();
  const rows = tableElem.querySelectorAll('tr');
  
  // remove previous wrappers
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/48573634/104380
  tableBody.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(w => {
    w.replaceWith(...w.childNodes)
  });
  
  // create a wrapper which hides its content:
  const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
  wrapper.setAttribute('hidden', true);
  
  rows.forEach(function(row){
    const text = row.textContent.toLowerCase();
    
    if (str.length && !text.includes(str)) {
      // replace row with wrapper and put the row inside it
      row.replaceWith(wrapper);
      wrapper.appendChild(row);
    }
  });
}

searchElem.addEventListener('keyup', search);
```

```css
tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  background: pink 
}
```

```html
<input type="search" placeholder="search">
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Apple<td>220
    <tr><td>Watermelon<td>465
    <tr><td>Orange<td>94
    <tr><td>Pear<td>567
    <tr><td>Cherry<td>483
    <tr><td>Strawberry<td>246
    <tr><td>Nectarine<td>558
    <tr><td>Grape<td>535
    <tr><td>Mango<td>450
    <tr><td>Blueberry<td>911
    <tr><td>Pomegranate<td>386
    <tr><td>Carambola<td>351
    <tr><td>Plum<td>607
    <tr><td>Banana<td>292
    <tr><td>Raspberry<td>912
    <tr><td>Mandarin<td>456
    <tr><td>Jackfruit<td>976
    <tr><td>Papaya<td>200
    <tr><td>Kiwi<td>217
    <tr><td>Pineapple<td>710
    <tr><td>Lime<td>983
    <tr><td>Lemon<td>960
    <tr><td>Apricot<td>647
    <tr><td>Grapefruit<td>861
    <tr><td>Melon<td>226
    <tr><td>Coconut<td>868
    <tr><td>Avocado<td>385
    <tr><td>Peach<td>419
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That is an interesting solution but it's arguably more work than just adding/removing a class per row.

Comment: Not that much work :) you don't have a choice anyway since CSS is quite limited, so the best way is to use the `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child` (which matches all children without caring for their type), and then you to bypass the element type problem, you simply manipulate it to be of different node, instead of toggling the a class. it's a reasonable approach without going full-js with this, maintaining the full list list in-memory and only rendering what is needed.

Comment: Even on a huge list of items, this should still be performant.