# CSS nth-chlld that works with only visible elements?

Tags: html, css

I get that `:nth-child` is actually checking "children" vs "visible children" but is there a selector that would work with visible children?

Imagine I have table, I make odd rows a different color

[image]

I have a search filter that hides rows that don't match the search. Now when I search the rows are no longer alternating colors.

[image]

Of course I can go add/remove classes to every element which I'm basically doing already to hide/show them but I thought I'd ask if there was a CSS way to do it.

```js
const searchElem = document.querySelector('input');
const tableElem = document.querySelector('table');

function search() {
  const str = searchElem.value.toLowerCase();
  const rows = tableElem.querySelectorAll('tr');

  rows.forEach(function(row){
    const text = row.textContent.toLowerCase();
    if (str.length && !text.includes(str)) {
      row.classList.add('hide');
    } else {
      row.classList.remove('hide');
    }
  });
}

searchElem.addEventListener('keyup', search);
```

```css
tr {
  background-color: #CDF;
}

tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #DEF;
}

thead>tr {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" placeholder="search">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Amount</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Apple</td><td>220</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Watermelon</td><td>465</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Orange</td><td>94</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Pear</td><td>567</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cherry</td><td>483</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Strawberry</td><td>246</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Nectarine</td><td>558</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Grape</td><td>535</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Mango</td><td>450</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Blueberry</td><td>911</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Pomegranate</td><td>386</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Carambola</td><td>351</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Plum</td><td>607</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Banana</td><td>292</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Raspberry</td><td>912</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Mandarin</td><td>456</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Jackfruit</td><td>976</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Papaya</td><td>200</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Kiwi</td><td>217</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Pineapple</td><td>710</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Lime</td><td>983</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Lemon</td><td>960</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Apricot</td><td>647</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Grapefruit</td><td>861</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Melon</td><td>226</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Coconut</td><td>868</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Avocado</td><td>385</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Peach</td><td>419</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have provided you with an answer the actual legal discussion regarding this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73820234/104380

Comment: thank you to whoever closed this. Sorry my search skills didn't find the existing question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no selector but if you are open to a specific solution for this case then you can rely on gradient like below:

```js
const searchElem = document.querySelector('input');
const tableElem = document.querySelector('table');

function search() {
  const str = searchElem.value.toLowerCase();
  const rows = tableElem.querySelectorAll('tr');

  rows.forEach(function(row){
    const text = row.textContent.toLowerCase();
    if (str.length && !text.includes(str)) {
      row.classList.add('hide');
    } else {
      row.classList.remove('hide');
    }
  });
}

searchElem.addEventListener('keyup', search);
```

```css
thead>tr {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

table {
  position:relative; /* relative to all the table */
  z-index: 0;
}
td {
  line-height: 1.2em; /* the height */
  clip-path: inset(0); /* clip the pseudo element to td */
}
tbody td:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      #CDF  0 calc(1.2em + 4px), /* height   + 2*border-spacing */
      #DEF  0 calc(2.4em + 8px)  /* 2*height + 4*border-spacing */
    ); 
}
```

```html
<input type="search" placeholder="search">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Amount</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Apple</td><td>220</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Watermelon</td><td>465</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Orange</td><td>94</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Pear</td><td>567</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cherry</td><td>483</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Strawberry</td><td>246</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Nectarine</td><td>558</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Grape</td><td>535</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Mango</td><td>450</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Blueberry</td><td>911</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Pomegranate</td><td>386</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Carambola</td><td>351</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Plum</td><td>607</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Banana</td><td>292</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Raspberry</td><td>912</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Mandarin</td><td>456</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Jackfruit</td><td>976</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Papaya</td><td>200</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Kiwi</td><td>217</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Pineapple</td><td>710</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Lime</td><td>983</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Lemon</td><td>960</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Apricot</td><td>647</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Grapefruit</td><td>861</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Melon</td><td>226</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Coconut</td><td>868</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Avocado</td><td>385</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Peach</td><td>419</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution though it sounds very brittle. Like if a row gets taller because its content is too big or because the user's window is thin (like a phone) then there'd be issues