# target and remove containing parent div tag not the contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a section of code which I don't have full control over which includes a Div with no class or id. I'd like to remove the opening and closing tag of this Div and keep the existing content, but not sure how to target this and remove ?

currently...

```
<li id="foo" class="underline">

<div>
<input id="username" name="username" required="required" class="validate" type="text">
</div>

<label for="username">Username</label>

</li>
```

the final result i would like...

```
<li id="foo" class="underline">

<div class="mynewdiv">

<input id="bar" name="bar" required="required" class="validate" type="text">
<label for="bar">Username</label>

</div>

</li>
```

I have control to add teh newDiv.  My question has similarities to [how can I remove wrapper (parent) without removing the child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261197/how-can-i-remove-wrapper-parent-without-removing-the-child)
but i'm not sure how to properly target this unnamed div (with closest?). Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is here to help with code you wrote but SO is not here to write code for you.

Comment: Why can't you just give the `<div>` an id or remove the `<div>` from the html?  Does this have to be a change at run time?

Comment: I don't have full control over the code in the framework to change the <div> . Many thanks to Carsten for his answer. Sorry I didn't think my code attempts that good to be worth adding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.append()` on your `div` and inside that find the `label`

```js
$(".underline div").append(function(){
  return $(this).next("label");
}).addClass("mynewdiv");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="foo" class="underline">

  <div>
    <input id="username" name="username" required="required" class="validate" type="text">
  </div>

  <label for="username">Username</label>

</li>
```

Comment: instead of `#foo` use `.underline` . May be he has more elements with same id(Accidently) and class.  in that case Class will work but id will not work.Also add a note regarding this too

Comment: @AlivetoDie True, I've took your advice and changed the code, thanks

Comment: This worked brilliantly thanks and i used a common class on the list elements.