# remove parent without removing childs in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261197/how-can-i-remove-wrapper-parent-element-without-removing-the-child) to remove parent without remove childs, but it don't work if the child node is a node type `3` (text)

```
<div>
    <h1>
        <u>
            Hello world
            <i> How are you ? </i>
        </u>
    </h1>
</div>
```

For example, I want to remove `<u>` tag (parent of `Hello world` node type text and `i`) using vanilla javascript.

After removing `u` tag I would like to have:

```
<div>
    <h1>
        Hello world
        <i> How are you ? </i>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your goal?

Comment: So... `element.parentNode.outerHTML = element.parentNode.innerHTML`? Or do you need to preserve all the JS event bindings etc. as well? (in which case, please [refine your question](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I would recommend rather element.parentElement.outerHTML then parentNode. For more info go here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685739/difference-between-dom-parentnode-and-parentelement
but basically it's safer option.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is short

Using the https://stackoverflow.com/users/7230746/tom-oeser answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261197/how-can-i-remove-wrapper-parent-element-without-removing-the-child) redefining the logic taken text node parent first.

```
function unwrap(node) {
    node = node.parentNode;
    node.replaceWith(...node.childNodes);
}
```